# CreateProcess Windows.h c++ how to run a function as a Process?

Tags: c++, process

I have this function ( the function gets a command as a parameter and executes something , I creating something like custom cmd:

```
int execute(Line* line)
{
    string command = line->command;
    if (command == "echo")
    {
        cout << line->parameter << endl;
    }
    else if (command == "dir")
    {
        cout << ExePath() << endl;
    }
    else if (command == "cd")
    {
        const char* newDir = line->parameter.c_str();
        if (!SetCurrentDirectory(newDir)) {
            std::cerr << "Error setting current directory: #" << GetLastError() << endl;
            return 1; // quit if we couldn't set the current directory
        }
        std::cout << "Set current directory to " << newDir << '\n';
    }
    else if (command == "exit")
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

how can I run it through CreateProcess method of windows.h ?

Comment: For `CreateProcess`, you need an executable. You'll have to compile this function into one (wrapping it up in `main`), and use the resulting executable in `CreateProcess` in another program.

Comment: SetCurrentDiretory() is for the current process only. When your process exits, the calling process will not have its directory changed.